# IntelliJ: Installing plugins manually on Macbook OS X

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

All guides I search for have nothing related to Mac. The plugins menu option is accessible via <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + S</kbd> (`Settings` menu) in Windows but on Mac, no such exists. When I go `File`, there is not even a Settings menu.

Closest is a `Default Settings` which gives the attached screenshot. No plugins options there that allows me to select the zip file for Ruby that I wish to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Mac the menu is caused **Preferences**, use `File` | **Preferences** or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> shortcut.

See also the [official settings/preferences documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-preferences-dialog.html) and [installing plugins](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/installing-updating-and-uninstalling-repository-plugins.html) documentation.